# copying a file to a network device

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using netmiko library to send a command to scp a file to the remote network device. My program is failing when it prompts for a password. Is there any way this password could be defined in the program itself? I have hundreds of network devices to copy a file.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

agg01 = {
   "device_type": "cisco_nxos",
   "ip": "10.1.30.229",
   "username": "admin",
   "password": "XXXX"
  }

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**agg01)

output = net_connect.send_config_set("copy scp://root@X.X.X.X/home/u/test bootflash:test vrf management")

print output
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this. You can also use `getpass` to have a ready to go username but prompted for a password to execute.

```
ciscoswitch = {
    'host': deviceName,
    'username': 'xxxxx',
    'password': 'xxxxx',
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
}
```